# Unique Key Violation in SQL Server - Is it safe to assume Error 2627?

Tags: sql-server-2005, unique-constraint

I need to catch violation of `UNIQUE` constraints in a special way by a C# application I am developing. Is it safe to assume that `Error 2627` will always correspond to a violation of this kind, so that I can use

```
if (ThisSqlException.Number == 2627)
{
    // Handle unique constraint violation.
}
else
{
    // Handle the remaing errors.
}
```

?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

2627 is unique constraint (includes primary key), 2601 is unique index

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages
WHERE text like '%duplicate%' and text like '%key%' and language_id = 1033
```

Comment: @gbn What is the difference between unique constraint and unique index? Don't both enforce indices?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx - In summary, we can safely conclude that there's no practical difference between a unique constraint and a unique index other than the fact that the unique constraint is also listed as a constraint object in the database.

Comment: @bfhd that is for SQL Server 2000. Very old. There are differences in key vs constratints such a INCLUDE and WHERE clauses. I never use constraints, too inflexible,

Comment: I want to add that `message_id` is reused for all languages. So even if you're not using English, the message returned will be different, but the `message_id` stays the same.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a handy extension method I wrote to find these:

```
    public static bool IsUniqueKeyViolation(this SqlException ex)
    {
        return ex.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().Any(e => e.Class == 14 && (e.Number == 2601 || e.Number == 2627 ));
    }
```

Comment: Is the class check really necessary, and if so, why?

Answer (score 4):

Within an approximation, yes.

If you search the MS error and events site for SQL Server, error 2627, you should hopefully reach [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.0&EvtID=2627&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&LCID=1033)<sup>1</sup>, which indicates that the message will always concern a duplicate key violation (note which parts are parameterized, and which not):

```
Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>As @2020-06-18, [Database engine errors and events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-2000-to-2999) would be the correct page to go to

Comment: What do you mean by "within an approximation"?

Comment: @User - all I meant was that I can't think of anything else that will complain about duplicate keys, but the message is unfortunately parameterized on the type of constraint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, link to [this page] leads to content of Microsoft Docs. was it intended?