# Identify type of exception in ExceptionHandler of Servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack-bsd

The ExceptionHandler(set inside the overridden Configure method of AppHostBase) of servicestack has the 'exception' parameter of generic Exception type in the lambda.

```
this.ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpResp, operationName, exception) =>
{
    if(exception is ArgumentException)
    {
      // some code
    }
}
```

Inside the lambda, I wish to add a specific condition if the exception is of `ArgumentException` type.
Is there any way to identify which specific type of exception was thrown?
Checking the type with 'is' keyword is not working as given by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270023/how-to-determine-if-an-exception-is-of-a-particular-type)

FYI, a custom ServiceRunner is implemented for the servicestack instance that we use.

Comment: As far as I understand the answer in the linked question it IS working!?

Comment: On yes it IS. If your code block is not running then the type of exception is not an ArguementException. Try debugging the code to see what type of exception it is or try `exception.GetType().ToString()`.

Comment: There is no `ExceptionHandler` in ServiceStack v4, if this is for [ServiceStack v3 you need to use the \[servicestack-bsd\] hash tag](https://github.com/servicestackv3/servicestackv3#support).

Comment: I checked again, but the exception object for some reason cannot be recognised as an `ArgumentException` inside the `ExceptionHandler`. Finally, the solution as answered below works.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code that caused the `ArgumentException` was

```
return serializer.Deserialize(querystring, TEMP);
```

For some reason, the exception object cannot be recognised as an `ArgumentException` inside the `ExceptionHandler`

```
this.ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpResp, operationName, exception) =>
{
    httpResp.StatusCode = 500;
    bool isArgEx = exception is ArgumentException; // returns false        
    if(isArgEx)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Although, as mentioned in the link(pls refer question) the **InnerException** can be identified using `is` keyword.

Hence the solution applied was to throw the `ArgumentException` as an inner exception as follows:

```
public const string ARG_EX_MSG = "Deserialize|ArgumentException";

try
{
    return serializer.Deserialize(querystring, TEMP);
}
catch(ArgumentException argEx)
{
    throw new Exception(ARG_EX_MSG, argEx);
}
```

Hence, now the `ExceptionHandler` code is:

```
this.ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpResp, operationName, exception) =>
{
    httpResp.StatusCode = 500;
    bool isArgEx = exception.InnerException is ArgumentException; // returns true
    if(isArgEx)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```