# How to handle Duplicate Key Exception in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4

Does anyone have a simple way of handling this exception when updating a record to one that already exists in the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate key exception from Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967140/duplicate-key-exception-from-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
catch (UpdateException ex)
{
    SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;

    if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == ??????)   
    {
        //Place you exception code handling here..    
    }
    else  
    {

        throw; //(bubble up)    
    }
}
```

This is a simple solution, but you may have issues in the future should the error number change which is unlikely).

Comment: If you're going to [copy an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3967158/298053) (down to the number of question marks), please be sure to cite it.