# Why is exception of type SqlException not being caught by try/catch SqlException?

Tags: c#, try-catch, sqlexception

I have the following code:

```
    try
    {
        Data.CreateUserAndAccount.ExecuteProcedure(accountName, firstName, lastName, email, password);
        return String.Empty;
    }
    catch (SqlException databaseError)
    {
        string result = IdentifyError(databaseError);
        return result;
    }
    catch  (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

I am intentionally throwing SQL exceptions by violating a unique key. However, the exception is caught by `Exception` and not `SqlException`. When I examine the `InnerException` details, the exception is of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

[image: InnerException Details]

Why is the SQL exception only being caught by the generic `Exception`?

Comment: Because `SqlException` is the `InnerException`, presumably. What's the actual exception type?

Comment: It could be UpdateException/DbUpdateException, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967140/duplicate-key-exception-from-entity-framework

Comment: The actual exception type is `EntityCommandExecutionException` @John @user10954641 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the exception is of type `EntityCommandExecutionException` which is derived from `DataException`.

I originally intended to perform some logic on `SqlException.Number`, which is why I was trying to catch a `SqlException`.

However, to solve this, catch `DataException` and then cast the `InnerException` to `SqlException`:

```
try
{
    Data.CreateUserAndAccount.ExecuteProcedure(accountName, firstName, lastName, email, password);
    return String.Empty;
}
catch (DataException procedureError)
{
    SqlException sqlError = (SqlException)procedureError.InnerException;
    string result = IdentifyError(sqlError);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're trying to catch `SqlException`, but that's not the exception type: it's the InnerException.

If [user10954641](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10954641/user10954641) is right, and its an `UpdateException`, you could simply catch that:

```
try
{
}
catch (UpdateException e)
{
}
```

If it's a different exception, then catch whatever exception type is actually thrown. Alternatively, you could conditionally catch exceptions where the InnerException is `SqlException`:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception e) when (e.InnerException is SqlException)
{
}
```

If you're wondering why `catch (SqlException)` doesn't work, consider the following code:

```
public void ThrowException()
{
    try
    {
        MakeDatabaseCall();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Uh oh!", e);
    }
}

public void MakeDatabaseCall()
{
    throw new SqlException();
}
```

A call to `ThrowException()` will ultimately produce an error form `MakeDatabaseCall()`, but the exception type will not be `SqlException` because we're wrapping it in another exception (in this case the exception base class): `Exception`. But, because we're passing the exception thrown by `MakeDatabaseCall()` into the constructor, our "Uh oh!" exception will contain the `SqlException` in its `InnerException` field.

When you use `try`/`catch(ExceptionType e)`, you're instructing .NET to pattern match the exception before deciding which `catch` statement to enter. For the sake of illustration, the two pieces of code below are *roughly equivalent*:

```
try
{
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    //catches an SqlException
}
```

and

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception e) when (e is SqlException)
{
    //catches an SqlException
}
```

Clearly in our `ThrowException` example, `Exception` is not derived from `SqlException`, so `catch (SqlException e)` won't match.